# How could I initialize an array of struct to null?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
    typedef struct 
    {
        char*title;
        int year;
        int length; //in minutes
    } record;

    record list[1024];
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<1024;++j)
        list[j]=NULL;
```

I am trying to initialize an array of struct and let each element point to null initially. gcc gives me an error "incompatible types when assigning to type 'record' from type 'void*". How could I solve it? The purpose of doing this is when I access an element I am able to see if it has data or just empty.

Comment: People often use `memset(list, '\0', sizeof(list));`.

Comment: [`memset()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)

Comment: Your array is not an array of pointers to `record`s, it is an array of  `record` values.  You cannot set the elements of the array to `NULL` because they are not pointers.  This is not java...

Comment: I wanted a array of pointers not struct..Thank you.

Comment: @pat: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: You declare an array of pointers as `record *list[1024];` and you can still zero/nullify the pointers with `memset(list, '\0', sizeof(list))` and you might then test `if (list[2] == 0)` (or `NULL` in place of 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list[1024];` is array of object of your struct, which you access like

```
list[j].title;
list[j].year;
list[j].length;
```

What you are doing is:

```
list[j]=NULL
```

`list[j]` is of type `record`, NULL is `void*`. I guess this is not what you have in mind.

Either initialize individual elements in the struct by accessing them individually or use `memset` as suggested by others.

Answer (score 7):

You can initialize your array at declaration time this way:

```
record list[1024] = {{0}};
```

Comment: How could I check if there is no element in this block? for example list[2] is empty, should I use if(list[2]==0) ?

Comment: You can use `title` member as a sentinel to mean an element has not been initialized: `if (list[2].title == NULL)`

Comment: @Robin: when you allocate an array of 1024 entries, then all 1024 entries are allocated, present.  You can test whether there's a name using `list[2].title == 0` (or `list[2].title == NULL`), but the space is allocated.

Comment: @ouah: I didn't downvote, but whoever did probably thought you didn't really answer the question. There's no such thing as a null structure, except perhaps by convention. A `record` object with `title==NULL`, `year==0`, and `length==0` could be a valid record.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it one at a time in a for loop, it would look like this

```
for(j=0;j<1024;++j)
    list[j]=(record){0,0,0};
```

I would suggest using `memset(list,0,1024*sizeof(record))`

or `bzero(list, 1024*sizeof(record))`

If you want to do it with pointers, then you could declare your array like this:

```
record * list[1024];
```

Then you could set each one to `NULL` like you are and malloc each one when you're ready for it.

Comment: You should probably mention that `(record){0,0,0}` is a C99 compound literal, not least because it probably isn't supported by MSVC.  Is there a good reason to use `1024 * sizeof(record)` rather than just `sizeof(list)`, which will automatically change to the correct size if the dimension of `list` is changed from 1024 to some other number?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I can't think of a good reason not to use `sizeof(list)`, it's just not what I familiar with.  I would be most comfortable defining a macro for `RECORDS_IN_LIST` because I always feel bad if there is a number in my code that has no name.  Then I would have `RECORDS_IN_LIST*sizeof(record)` which I find very readable.

Comment: If performance was a consideration, 1 large allocation will take less time than 1024 small ones.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is not an array of pointers to `record`s, it is an array of `record` values. You cannot set the elements of the array to `NULL` because they are not pointers. This is not java...